# Jquery Webcam Redirect after upload

Tags: php, jquery, webcam

I am new to JQuery and PHP, and I am trying to implement a jquery webcam in a site, I used this tutorial to implement one, http://tutorialzine.com/2011/04/jquery-webcam-photobooth/. I succesfully integrated it and the upload to file system works, My problem is how can I force redirect a page after clicking the upload button?

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: you can't use window.location = "http://www.example.com/"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location = "http://....";`

You have to place it in the function that "saves" and places the image in the grid because if you bind the Button just to redirect, it is possible that the image will not be saved

Comment: I am also trying to remove the webcam permission popup, and open the webcam by default, is that possible?

Comment: Hi John and Flukey, window.location is not working, I place it on the function after the upload.

Comment: window.location redirects to a url for sure. Maybe you must place it somewhere else. The permission popup cannot be removed. Only if the user has set his privacy options to be very low. This is something you cannot control!